# JQuery Dialog in Javascript

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display a dialog and I am not able to dismiss it when I click on Ok button. I am not sure.. what I am doing wrong, can you please let me know?

When I try to put this code in jsfiddle, it is not showing any output :(

```
function alert_popup_msg(_msg)
{
   var id = "dialog_" + (new Date()).getTime();
   var popDiv = "<div id='" + id + "'><div  class=\"popup-background\"><label class=\"color-white no-text-shadow center-align font-helv-16-bold std-padding-a\">Alert</label><label class=\"color-white no-text-shadow center-align font-helv-12-reg std-padding-a\">"+_msg+"</label><div class=\"center-align\"><a class=\"btn-simple-black-orange btn-text btn-login\" id=\"okButtonCallBack\">Ok</a></div></div></div> ";                                             
   $.mobile.activePage.append(popDiv).trigger("pagecreate");
   //addEventListener_(id);
   $( "#" + id ).dialog({
      modal: true,

    });
   //$("#" + id).popup();
   $("#" + id).dialog("open");
   $("#okButtonCallBack").click(function(event){
        $("#" + id).dialog("close");

   });

};
```

Comment: Is this a jquery ui dialog? If yes, try using the built-in button initialization code

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message Please refer this link

Comment: Did you check if there are any errors in the console? more importantly do you know if it is event going inside the handler
?

Comment: Updated the JS fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/h7LDf/12/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by commenting this line.

```
// $("#" + id).dialog("open");
```